# Finding this Probability Density Function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

I would much appreciate if you help me out with this problem

Let $X \sim Unif(0,1)$

Find the density of $Y = -\lambda^{-1} \log(1-X)$ with $\lambda > 0$

Then calculate $P(Y>t+s|Y>t)$ for $t,s >0$

So far i´ve got

$F_Y (y) = P[Y \le y]$ $=$ $P[1/y^{\lambda} \le log(1-x)]$ $=$

$P[X \le 1-10^{1/y^{\lambda}}]$ this is $F_X(1-10^{1/y^\lambda})$

Im stuck there. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: As in the Answer by @AndreNicolas, the result is exponential. An important application of this exercise is to simulate observations from such an exponential distribution. Pseudorandom number generators typically produce values that behave as if they are from Unif(0,1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach through the cumulative distribution function is reasonable, but there are troubles with the algebra. I am interpreting $\log$ as the natural logarithm. Minor modification will take care of things if we interpret $\log$ as logarithm to the base $10$.

We have for suitable $y$
$$\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr\left(-\frac{\log(1-X)}{\lambda}\le y\right)=\Pr(\log(1-X)\ge -\lambda y).\tag{1}$$
The right-hand side of (1) is equal to
$$\Pr(1-X\ge e^{-\lambda y}),$$
which is
$$\Pr(X\le 1-e^{-\lambda y}).$$
For $y\ge 0$, this is $1-e^{-\lambda y}$ (for $y\lt 0$ it is $0$).

Thus the cdf of $Y$ is $1-e^{-\lambda y}$ if $y\ge 0$, and $0$ otherwise. Differentiate to find the density. But from the cdf we recognize the exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda$.